# Laravel hasManyThrough relationship gives empty collection

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, relationship

I'm trying to get all filters belonging to a custom_view. For example: `$user->custom_views->first->filters`

The code below gives me an empty collection. I have tried everything, but cant wrap my head around why i'm getting an empty collection. Maybe somebody can see what i`m doing wrong here?

```
user      custom_views   custom_view_filters   filters
----      ------------   -------------------   -------
id        id             id                    id
          user_id        custom_view_id
                         filter_id
```

User model:

```
public function custom_views(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\CustomView');
}
```

CustomView model:

```
public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}

public function filters(){
    return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Filter', 'App\CustomViewFilter', 'custom_view_id', 'id');
}
```

CustomViewFilter model:

```
no relations defined
```

Filters model

```
public function custom_views(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\CustomView', 'custom_view_filter', 'custom_view_id', 'filter_id');
}
```

Comment: There seems to be a direct relationship between custom_view and filter, a simple many to many relationship using a pivot table. Am I wrong?

Comment: Yes, you are right.  `return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Filter')->withPivot('custom_view_id', 'filter_id', 'position');` does work. I found the problem, my table was named `custom_view_filters` while laravel was trying to find `custom_view_filter` .  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

change `filters` method in `CustomView` to this:

```
public function filters(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Filter', 'custom_view_filter','filter_id','custom_view_id');
}
```